# Razor Code Block, Can't Access Local Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am simply trying to access a variable, one which I just created in the line above, and I can't do it!

```
@{
    public class url
    {
        public string href;
        public string title;   
    }
    List<url> urls = new List<url>();
    urls.
}
```

When I try to do `urls.Add()` it says, "*...urls is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:- But i dont't think if it is a good idea to define classes inside a Razor template. You should define it in the class file and use it as a model or using `using`
 namespace.

```
@functions {
    public class url
    {
        public string href;
        public string title;   
    }

}
@{

    List<url> urls = new List<url>();

    urls.Add(new url());
}
```

Comment: Good call, this works.  I was not aware of the @functions block.  Will accept in 2 mins.

Comment: No problem.. But remember main purpose of @function is to define reusable code like defining properties, methods etc in the template.. I had also never tried defining a class inside thought its purpose is not that...

Comment: Thanks, I was just seeing if I could do it.  I probably won't use this in production.

Comment: Theoratically possible, but read through it once and if possible try having the it defined as a class file in your project and use it in your view.